# Rails - how to join two relation based on single View?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've defined a view in my Rails application following [guide](https://rietta.com/blog/2013/11/28/rails-and-sql-views-for-a-report/)

So, currently I have this class:

```
class GoldenResult < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :latest_builds, -> { select('MAX(id) as id').group(:platform_id, :release_id, :configuration_id) }

end
```

I'd like to perform the following join:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_dev.report_golden_results e 
join (SELECT max(id) as 'id' 
from performance_dev.report_golden_results 
group by platform_id, release_id, configuration_id) s 
ON s.id = e.id;
```

the issue is that I don't know how to access the **ON** join variables (i.e.    `ON s.id = e.id`)

What is the rails conventional way of creating this query?

thanks!

Comment: An SQL way would be using **union** (or **intersect**?), I think. Rails' ActiveRecord is built on `arel`, so this **might** help, not sure: http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/05/more-than-enough-arel.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by using the following query:

```
GoldenResult.joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as 'id'
                                FROM report_golden_results
                                GROUP BY platform_id, release_id, configuration_id) latest_builds
                    ON latest_builds.id=report_golden_results.id")
```

This is a **workaround** as I still don't know how to access the scope in the JOIN but it works..!

(i.e. - in this solution I'm not using the scope at all).